# Terraform: all Azure subscriptions from azurerm_subscriptions

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Good morning,

I’m using Terraform 0.12 with the Azure Provider 2.0.0. I have the following block to retrieve all subscriptions starting with “sub-”:

```
data "azurerm_subscriptions" "mgt" {
    display_name_prefix = "sub-"
}
```

Now I would like to somehow automatically create the different “azurerm_subscription” objects from this one. Is there any way to kind of loop over all those subscriptions and create the appropriate “azurerm_subscription” objects?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, the `display_name_prefix` is not expected in [`data "azurerm_subscription"`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/subscription.html)block, what do you try to do? Also, you can use this data source to access information about an existing Subscription. You can not create new subscription objects from it.

Comment: The display_name for filtering works just fine. The output gives me back all the subscriptions according to the filter. 

What I’m trying to do is having one single data source with all subscriptions instead of having e.g. 20 times a data source of type “azurerm_subscription”. The only problem I have then, is that I cannot easily access the attributes of a specific subscription, as I have to access them by index and not by e.g. its name.

Comment: Yes, you have to access the attributes of a specific subscription by index because the `data "azurerm_subscriptions"` output all the filtered subscriptions. It's a list not a string of subscription. So is this your problem?

Comment: Currently, the "looping" constructs in Terraform require the values to be known before runtime. You could `for_each` through a pre-defined list of subscriptions, but not through a list populated by running Terraform. https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find index of your subscription, then refer to that index:

```hcl
data "azurerm_subscriptions" "available" {
}

locals {
  subscription_index = index(data.azurerm_subscriptions.available.subscriptions.*.display_name, "mysubscription")
}

output "azurerm_subscription" {
  value = element(data.azurerm_subscriptions.available.subscriptions, local.subscription_index)
}
```

You can also create map from the "azurerm_subscriptions".
Then create "azurerm_subscription" using for_each and reference to specific data using name:

```hcl
locals {
  subscriptions_map = {
    for obj in data.azurerm_subscriptions.available.subscriptions.* : obj.display_name => obj
  }
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "sub" {
  for_each = local.subscriptions_map

  subscription_id     = each.value.subscription_id
}

output "data" {
  value = data.azurerm_subscription.sub["mysubscription"].subscription_id
}
```